# Como conseguir que un footer se mantenga en el fondo sin que sobrepase otros elementos?

Tags: html, laravel, css3

Estoy teniendo problemas para colocarlo actualmente esta con el atributo absolute, el problema es que debido a esto funciona como si fuese transparente y los objetos lo atraviesan.

https://i.gyazo.com/2cdc72727b7140cd6de1eda90e2d7f98.mp4

Me gustaria que se mantuviera un espacio de forma que esto no ocurriese.

Estoy usando tailwindcss este es el trozo de codigo que pertenece al div principal del footer.

```
<div style="background-color: #0080ff" class="container bg-grey-lighter absolute pin-b pin-x p-8 pt-3 pb-3">
```

[image: El div esta contenido dentro de la etiqueta footer]

Al usarlo como static se mantiene en un punto fijo por lo que no varia dependiendo de el tamaño o la resolucion de la pantalla

[image: Se mantiene estatico :L]

Comment: ¿Por que tu div que es un footer debe estar en position absolute? Ademas te recomiendo usar HTML5 y el tag para el footer es `<footer>`

Comment: Vale me explicare mejor, ese div esta contenido en un footer y es el aspecto visual del footer

Comment: ok, pero vuelvo hacer la misma pregunta anterior. ¿Por que debe ser absolute? si lo que quieres es dejar el `footer` fijo en pagina mira la respuesta que te dejaron abajo.

Comment: Como respondi al otro chico, la idea no es que se mantenga fijo en pagina, si no que este al fondo de la pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la posicion de los elementos dependiendo del espacio en pantalla o `viewport` debes utilizar algo nuevo de CSS3 que es la unidades de medida en `vh`. Te dejo unos link para que leas y puedas ver [Link 1](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/unidades-vh-vw-css/) [Link 2](https://www.yunbitsoftware.com/blog/2017/06/22/viewport-units-css-que-es/)

me imagino que tienes algo como esto:

```
<header>
    <!-- TU HEADER -->
</header>
<main style="height: 100vh;">
    <!-- TU FORMULARIO -->
</main>
<footer>
    <!-- TU FOOTER -->
<footer>
```

Aca es donde debes jugar con el valor de height ya que como tienes un header un main y un footer no debería ser 100 ai no que menos. Guiate por los ejemplos en Internet de como utilizar esta nueva medida de css3

Comment: No era exactamente lo que necesitaba, pero gracias a esto ya se me ocurrio como hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

tienes que colocarle una pocision fixed, bottom 0 y un clear both

ejemplo:

```
  #footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;

}
```

no le pongas position absolute ya que intervendra con tu otros contenido de la web y otra cosa usa las etiquetas de html5 para el footer `<footer></footer>`

Comment: Tu respuesta hace que se mantenga todo el tiempo pegado al fondo de la pagina incluso cuando se hace scroll. No quiero que se mantenga pegado a la ventana del navegador.

Comment: entonces cual es tu objetivo tienes que ser mas espesifico que intentas lograr al hacer scroll?

Comment: Ya lo digo en la pregunta quiero que se mantenga en el fondo de la pagina, en ningun momento pregunto como hacer que se mantenga fijo en la pagina.
Que independiente del tamaño de la pagina o la resolucion de la pantalla se encuentre al fondo de esta, y que no sobrepase los otros objetos.

Comment: @JhackexMXY Entonces simplemente quilate el absolute y no le coloques nada, para que se comporte como un div con display block normal. Si no es esto lo que quieres creo que yo tampoco te entiendo

Comment: ok entonces con una poscision statica y el bottom o es suficiente amigo

Comment: Ya esta probado y no funciona

Comment: entonces si que no entendemos que quieres con eso  tu div deberia estar siempre al fondo  prueva agregando poniendo un height al body de 1400px para poder hacer scroll y ya veras

Comment: El body tiene un height de 100px, me estas diciendo que le tengo que poner un height absurdamente alto?

Comment: ok vamos por paso para poder ayudarte en verdad cual es el resultado que esperas ?

Comment: Que independiente del tamaño o resolucion de pantalla siempre aparezca al fondo de pagina, y digo pagina no ventana.

Comment: Quieres agregarle un valor de capa a tu footer entonces? hablamos de z-index o no? por que al igual que @andy sigo sin entender que es lo que quieres lograr. De hecho podríamos decir que la pregunta es confusa.

Comment: Ok ya entendí tu problema.

Comment: A ver, dependiendo del dispositivo que uses el tamaño de la pagina es diferente. Entonces quiero que independientemente del tamaño, siempre se mantenga al fondo del documento html.

Comment: ok segun entiendo no importa el tamano de la pantalla quieres que el height se mantenga estable osea que el header se mantenga arriba el footer en el fondo el contenido en su centro es eso?

Comment: SI exactamente eso

Comment: Utiliza un `height: 100vh;` en el contenido de tu formulario de login. Juega con este valor ya que seria una solucion para posicionar los elementos dependiendo del espacio en pantalla.

Comment: Entonces tengo que darle a todos los elementos una altura predeterminada? Actualmente en el documento ya utilizo una altura de 100vh para el body y html

Comment: si no te funciona el height:100vh; entonces utilisa `display:flex; y display:wrap;`

Comment: Dame unos segundos te estoy dando una respuesta mas completa.

Comment: Te deje una respuesta, si ya estas ocupando estas medidas en otros elementos debe estar por ahí tu problema. Revisa los link que te deje para que veas como se ocupa esta medida de css3.

Answer (score 0):

un saludo... la opcion de utilizar css de esta manera te servira en esta ocasion(REF#1):

```
  #footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
clear:both;
width:100%;
height:100px;}
```

si dentro de una pagina con contenido haces esto, el footer se pondra sobre algunos elementos, tambien sucederá en dispositivos móviles, ya que position:fixed, mantiene fijo el footer y con lo demas lo mantienes abajo... yo lo que hago para evitar esto es detectar el tamaño del scroll: referencia al tamaño del scroll javascript  utilizando(REF#2):

```
window.pageYOffset;
```

asi puedo preguntar si el scroll esta activo(REF#2) no es necesario utilizar el CSS de arriba (REF#1), Y si el scroll no esta activo, utilizo ese css, evitando ocasionar problemas en dispositivos moviles y en otras pantallas....
TAMBIEN COMO OTRA OPCION CREA UN DIV QUE ENCIERRE TU FORMULARIO, Y A ESTE AJUSTALO AL TAMAÑO DE LA PANTALLA CON ´window.innerHeight;´ Y LE RESTAS EL TAMAÑO DEL FOOTER

Answer (score 0):

En TailWindCSS usa la clase pin

```
<div class="relative h-24 w-24 bg-grey-light">
  <div class="pin-x pin-b h-8 bg-grey-darker"></div>
</div>
```